# CAS logout on session timeout using spring security

Tags: java, spring-security, cas

When using spring security with CAS what is the proper way to call cas logout on session time out and then redirect to re-authenciate??

```
 <security:http entry-point-ref="casAuthenticationEntryPoint" use-expressions="true">       
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/home" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>     

    <security:custom-filter after="CAS_FILTER" ref="casAuthenticationFilter" />
    <security:session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="concurrentSessionControlStrategy" /> 
    <security:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/cas-logout.jsp"/>       
 </security:http>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this [link](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/HOWTO+Configure+Single+Sign+On+Session+Timeout). You'll see that this configuration is setted in the CAS. The default is the session of the user expires after 2 hours of idleness and if you would accurate 
this behavior you must define the archive

```
/cas-server-webapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-configuration/ticketExpirationPolicies.xml
```